# Enabled scrolling for UITextView in self sizing cells, iOS8 and later

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have a self sizing table view cell in iOS8 and iOS9 and that cell contains UITextView as a subview. I want automatic resizing for my UITextView but with scrolling enabled. After several tests and investigations I found that scrolling for UITextView can't be enabled in self sizing cells. Am I right? If no can somebody provide a good link with example of how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to have the text view fit the cell:

```
    textView.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
```

Are you wanting the text view to expand as the user types? If so, you probably want to hook into the didSelectRowAtIndexPath callback and just show a modal view with a full screen text view.